# "adding" products to cart in vue not showing up in console.log

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

the code:
shop.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="products" v-for="Product in items" :key="Product.id" :Product="Product"
            v-on:add-To-Cart="addToCart($event)">
            <h1>{{ Product.name }}</h1> <img :src="Product.pic" width="400" /> <br>
            {{ Product.description }} <br>
            {{ "$" + Product.price }} <br>
            <button class="addToCart" @click="$emit('add-To-Cart', Product)">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Product from '../db.json';
    export default {
        name: 'shop',
        data() {
            return {
                items: Product
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addToCart(Product) {
                this.Product=Product
                console.log(this.Product)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

when I click the add to cart button it is not logging the product to the console

how can I fix that? and implement a shopping cart to my website?

Comment: please provide more information. for example, what is the output of the console.log instead of products?

Comment: @AliBahrami what do you mean? there is no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Custom events are emitted from vue components not from native html elements, the same for props, you can directly call the method `addToCart` from the click event handler :

```html
<template>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="products" v-for="Product in items" :key="Product.id" >
            <h1>{{ Product.name }}</h1> <img :src="Product.pic" width="400" /> <br>
            {{ Product.description }} <br>
            {{ "$" + Product.price }} <br>
            <button class="addToCart" @click="addToCart(Product)">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Product from '../db.json';
    export default {
        name: 'shop',
        data() {
            return {
                items: Product
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addToCart(Product) {
                this.items.push(Product)
                console.log(this.items)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why it is creating duplicates of the products? it should not do that. only log it to console or if you prefer, add it to a cart.

Answer (score 0):

I have a modified the code a little bit without any stylings applied. Please check the below snippet

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
   return {
     items: [{
      name: 'aaa',
      description: 'about aaa',
      pic: 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.taste.com.au%2Frecipes%2Fchocolate-cream-biscuits%2Fee3d0934-ccca-4fdf-8827-64f2fd2737e1&psig=AOvVaw1fEqbEmoJeGS0WmrnSy6pS&ust=1668580370820000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCICb2LbIr_sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD',
      price: 12,
     },
     {
      name: 'bbb',
      description: 'about bbb',
      pic: 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.taste.com.au%2Frecipes%2Fchocolate-cream-biscuits%2Fee3d0934-ccca-4fdf-8827-64f2fd2737e1&psig=AOvVaw1fEqbEmoJeGS0WmrnSy6pS&ust=1668580370820000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCICb2LbIr_sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD',
      price: 12,
     }],
     cartItems:[],
    };
   },
  methods: {
   addToCart(item) {
     this.cartItems.push({...item});
   },
 }
});
```

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
        <div class="products" v-for="product in items" :key="product.id">
            <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1> <img :src="product.pic" width="400" /> <br>
            {{ product.description }} <br>
            {{ "$" + product.price }} <br>
            <button class="addToCart" @click="addToCart(product)">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it says "item is not defined" + what is the ...items in the addtocart method?

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check

Comment: `...item` is actually used to push the object into the array with the different reference

Comment: what is ...??? there is a error

Comment: its a rest operator that was introduced part of ES6

Comment: is not working well. as it keeps creating new elements(the push method)